# HTTP Resteasy client SSL trust all certificate

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, resteasy

I searched any possible solution to trust all certificate using Resteasy client, but I could not find a single working solution. I'm beginning to think that there is no way to do this using Resteasy 2.2.1.

Now, this is a sample of what I've done so far for a normal HTTP connection using resteasy client setting a proxy:

```java
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
ApacheHttpClientExecutor ace;
String proxyhost  = getProperty("proxyHost");
Integer proxyport = getProperty("proxyPort", Integer.class);
boolean useProxy = (proxyhost != null);
if(useProxy){
    hc.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(proxyhost, proxyport);
    ace = new ApacheHttpClientExecutor(hc);
} else {
    ace = new ApacheHttpClientExecutor();
}
ClientRequestFactory crf = new ClientRequestFactory(ace,uri);
```

Now, how can I tell to my `ClientRequestFactory` or my `ApacheHttpClientExecutor` or my `HttpClient` to trust all certificate?

Beware: I'm using Resteasy 2.2.1 (JBoss 5.1) I can't migrate to JBoss 7 or use a different resteasy version so I can't accept any answer that uses `ResteasyClientBuilder`

I can already see the good guy that answer "*You shouldn't trust all certificate, it's evil!*". This is an HTTP client used for Integration test, so it's pointless to consider (at this test level) the SSL certificate. I will absolutely **not** do this in production.

Comment: It's maybe duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257455/whats-an-easy-way-to-totally-ignore-ssl-with-java-url-connections/21257694#21257694

Comment: No, it's not! Because I'm talking about Resteasy Client, not HTTPUrlConnection nor base Apache HttpClient, I already check those answer without finding any useful information

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22444115/1328942

```java
private DefaultHttpClient createAllTrustingClient() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

        TrustStrategy trustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {

            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                LOG.info("Is trusted? return true");
                return true;
            }
        };

        SSLSocketFactory factory = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStrategy, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, factory));

        ThreadSafeClientConnManager mgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(registry);
        mgr.setMaxTotal(1000);
        mgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(1000);

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, new DefaultHttpClient().getParams());
        return client;
    }
```

And this is how it works:

```
@Test
public void testCatchingTheUnknownHostException() throws Exception {
    ApacheHttpClient4Executor apacheHttpClient4Executor = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(
            createAllTrustingClient());

    ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest(host, apacheHttpClient4Executor);
}
```

Tested it with Resteasy  2.3.2.Final (Jboss 7.1.1)

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the question was about Resteasy 2.2.1

Comment: The link is for 3* version, but my code is for the 2.3.2. it's the same major version, are the differences that big?